# Can not download files with different torrents, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, browser, download, bittorrent

*Can not download files.*

This is my friend's problem (just help him). He can download files with browsers, but not with torrents. How he tried to fix the problem:

1. **Download with another wi-fi** (he tried two different, both of them do work if he, for example, is playing or watching video);
2. **Download with another torrent** (UTorrent, BTorrent, MediaGet, MegaDownloader (the last is not accurate, he can't recollect the right name) etc.);
3. **Download with others torrent versions**;
4. **Redownload torrent**;
5. **Switch checks in parameters**;
6. **Change proxy-server**.

He's got Windows 10, the PC is not old (less than a year after purchase, the date of the PC I don't know, but it is not old);

In sum, he **can download files with browsers, but not with torrents**.

Any ideas to fix?

Edited: He tried to dwonload with two different wi-fi from two different providers and use mobile network or VPN - nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

It can be that his internet provider is blocking torrents.
My provider does that as well. You can ask him to try to share internet from his phone and then check if it works, or use a VPN connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, told him, thanks. But it seems like he tried to use his phone's internet. (I can't vote your answer 'cause I'm new here, sorry, I will mark as a right as soon as it works).

Comment: So he said that he tried to download something with torrents with 2 different wi-fi of 2 different providers. He also tried to share the internet connection from his phone and use VPN - nothing worked.

Comment: I would then try if I can ping / resolve the tracker used in the torrent and / or add other trackers. 
I would also try to download .torrent files and then double click on them in explorer in stead of using magnet links (or is he already using .torrent files?)
I would also try to take torrent files that have thousands of people that are downloading. To see if any download would start then (Maybe it is a NAT problem)

Comment: He tried to download different formats of files from many sites with many torrents on different wi-fis and VPNs and he also tried to turn off/on each checkmark in settings both of torrents and PC...